# Copy specific columns to another worksheet

Tags: excel, vba

I have a main table with 7 columns, codename "ShNote", I want to run a code that find a value of 20 on last column ("I"). After, it will copy automatically the name of clients (column D) and its values (based on condition must be equal to 20) on column I. 
I am expecting the macro will copy these data and paste on another sheet, codename ShPPT, on column C & D, starting row = 6.

Normally, I have 4 clients, why it only copiied 1 client 
Can you help me to look after the code please?

I am reading on some blogs that you can use array to optimize your code to become efficient

P.s: This is only the beginning of my code, on column I, I am looking for this range of value 
1. 20
2. 17-20 
3. 15 - 17 
4. 11 - 15 
5. < 11

Everytime my macro run, it copy automatically the client's name and its corresponding values.

```
Sub NoteLog()

'1. Copy the client's name and its note ranked by 4 particular conditions (20;17-20;15-17;11-15;<11)

Dim finalrow As Long, c As Long, i As Long, rowppt As Long, colppt As Long

finalrow = ShNote.Range("I" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
rowppt = ShPPT.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
colppt = ShPPT.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row

For c = 6 To finalrow
    If ShNote.Range("I" & c).Value = 20 Then
    ShNote.Range("D" & c).Copy
    ShPPT.Cells(rowppt + 6, 3).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
    ShNote.Range("I" & c).Copy
    ShPPT.Cells(colppt + 6, 4).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
    End If
Next c
  rowppt = rowppt + 1
  colppt = colppt + 1
```

End Sub

Comment: Do you really need a loop? Can't you just filter column I for 20 and then copy the whole range just once?

Comment: I need to write code for monthly report

Comment: I mean, the criteria to copy every row is that Column I equals to 20, so you don't need to loop, just filter column I to show only values equal to 20 and then copy the whole range. No need for arrays or anything else is just 1 operation.